# Date and Time in Log file

Tags: sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

I've the translated Sybase ASA 9 log file, and the log looks like

```
--UPDATE-1120-05402698411
UPDATE DBA.titulo_receber
   SET dt_pagto='2014/apr/28 11:06:08.593',
       id_situacao='BA',
       vl_pago=90,
       cd_empresa_baixa=5,
       cd_usuario_baixa=197,
       nr_recebimento=5015693,
       dt_manutencao='2014/apr/28 11:08:22.949895'
 WHERE cd_empresa=3
   AND nr_titulo=20154
   AND nr_parcela=5
   AND serie='CF05'
go
--INSERT-1120-05402698481
INSERT INTO DBA.mensagem(nr_mensagem,dt_mensagem,hora,cd_usuario_remetente,
      cd_usuario_destinatario,id_situacao,assunto,texto,id_confirmacao,
      dt_recebido,nr_mensagem_resposta,dt_mensagem_enviada,dt_ult_alteracao)
VALUES (50019297,'2014/apr/28 00:00','11:07:36.0',197,59,'N','TITULO BAIXADO','Empresa Venda: Loja3\x0D\x0AEmpresa Baixa: Loja5\x0D\x0ACliente: 3340-EZIONEI CONSTANTINO (Cliente da Loja3)\x0D\x0AT�tulo(s): 20154/05  R$ 90,00\x0D\x0ATOTAL PAGO: R$ 90,00','N',NULL,NULL,'2014/apr/28 11:06:08.593','2014/apr/28 11:08:22.952065')
go
--COMMIT-1120-05402701966
COMMIT WORK
go
```

I need to know the date and time in the "--UPDATE" / "--INSERT" and "--COMMIT" were executed in the db.

I can't find in the Sybase's help file nor in my search in Internet.

Kind Regards,
William Bertan